# How to identify notifications from a particular NSManagedObjectContext save operation?

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data

I'm writing an app that uses Core Data but syncs its data with a server over HTTP. I'm monitoring NSManagedObjectContext's notifications so I can respond to changes in the data.

**Updated based on initial responses:** Thanks for the suggestions. Seems like I need to explain better: I'm using Core Data within the app but posting changes to a server as well, monitoring notifications from the managed object context to do so.

At the same time I'm also polling the server for changes periodically. When a change comes down from the server I update the Core Data objects accordingly. But in that case *only*, I want to avoid posting the newly changed local data back to the server (since that's where it came from in the first place). In other words, either I want to suppress the notification on the save operation *or* when I receive that notification I want to recognize and ignore it.

I'm not currently doing anything fancy with concurrency or threads. If that means I can rely on managed object context's save notification's coming in in exactly the same order as my save operations, I can simply set a flag before the save in question. Will that work?

(And if it does, that still feels messy if I ever want to work asynchronously in the future. It would be nicer to have some way to tie the notification back to the particular save operation or suppress that save's notifications altogether.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting question!

I would say to use a `BOOL` flag if you're not using multithreading.

If you are using multithreading and targeting 10.6+, you should do all your Core Data operations (including setting that flag) on the same, concurrent Grand Central Dispatch (or GCD) serial queue.

You could set up that queue like so:

```
dispatch_queue_t dataQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Data Queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

You can then execute Core Data operations on that queue using:

```
dispatch_async(dataQueue, ^{
    //do work here
});
```

Don't forget to release the queue when you're done with it:

```
dispatch_release(dataQueue);
```

`dataQueue` could perhaps be used as an ivar or as a global variable accessed through some `+` method.

All operations sent to the queue will be executed serially (in the order they're submitted) so if everything is sent to the same queue, you should have no thread safety problems.

Read up on Grand Central Dispatch (which I personally think is a really cool API) at the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

As spudwaffle says you can get the context from the object pointer in the notification object.

Your merge callback method might look like this:

```
- (void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if (notification.object != self.context) {
        [self.context mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Sounds like I needed to be clearer with my question...updated above.